# Using MACROs to get the 'name' of function parameters

Tags: c++, function, macros

I've implemented a log function, that eventually is being used identically all over the code.

```
void func(int foo, int bar){
    log_api_call("foo", foo, "bar",bar)
    ...
}
```

so I've decided to make it easier and just extract the variable names.
so it would be something like

```
log_api_call(foo,bar)
```

or even better

```
log_api_call()
```

and it would expand to `log_api_call("foo", foo, "bar",bar)` somehow.
I have no idea even where to start to 'extract' the function variable names.
help would be much appreciated.

Edit:
I understand that what I've asked previously is outside of the C++ preprocessor capabilities, but can C MACROS  expand `log_api(a,b)` to `log_api_call("a", a, "b", b)` **for any number of parameters**?
for defined number the job is trivial.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible in standard C++11 (or standard C11 - which nearly shares its preprocessor with C++). The [C or C++ preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) don't know the [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) of your code passed to the compiler (because it is running *before* the actual parsing of your code).

> I have no idea even where to start to 'extract' the function variable names.

Notice that variable and function *names* are known only at compilation time (after preprocessing). So if you want them, you need to work during compilation. At execution time variables and functions names are generally lost (and you could [strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strip_(Unix)) your executable).

You could generate your C++ code (e.g.using some other preprocessor like [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) or M4, or writing your own thing).

You could customize your C++ compiler (e.g. with an extension in  [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/), or a GCC plugin) to e.g. have `log_api_call` invoke some new magic builtin (whose processing inside the compiler would do most of the job). This would take months and is very compiler specific, I don't think it is worth the pain.

You could parse [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debugging info (that would also take months, so I don't think it would be wise).

<sup>(I am implicitly thinking of C++ code compiled on a Linux system)</sup>

Read more about [aspect programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

If you want such powerful meta-programming facilities, C++ is the wrong programming language. Read more about the powerful macro system of Common Lisp...

> but can C MACROS expand `log_api(a,b)` to `log_api_call("a", a, "b", b)` for *any number* of parameters? for defined number the job is trivial.

No. You need a more powerful preprocessor to do that job (or write your own). For that specific need, you might consider customizing your [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) (e.g. write a hundred lines of ELisp code doing that extraction & expansion job *at edit time* for `emacs`).

<sup>PS In practice you could find some library (probably [boost](http://boost.org/)) limiting the arguments to some reasonable limit</sup>

Comment: Why wouldn't a macro be able to do this? I mean, of course not for any number, but for reasonable numbers (e.g. less than 20) You can use @Hwalter's solution or something similar.

Comment: In practice you'll indeed limit thar arguments to e.g. 20, and perhaps you could find some [boost](http://boost.org/) library doing that

Answer (score 6):

This isn't actually too difficult.

I'd recommend a slight change in spec though; instead of:

> expand `log_api(a,b)` to `log_api_call("a", a, "b", b)`

...it's more useful to expand something like `NAMED_VALUES(a,b)` to `"a",a,"b",b`.  You can then call `log_api(NAMED_VALUES(a,b))`, but your log_api can stay more generic (e.g., `log_api(NAMED_VALUES(a,b),"entering function")` is possible).  This approach also avoids a lot of complications about zero-argument cases.

```
// A preprocessor argument counter
#define COUNT(...) COUNT_I(__VA_ARGS__, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1,)
#define COUNT_I(_9,_8,_7,_6,_5,_4,_3,_2,_1,X,...) X
// Preprocessor paster
#define GLUE(A,B) GLUE_I(A,B)
#define GLUE_I(A,B) A##B
// chained caller
#define NAMED_VALUES(...) GLUE(NAMED_VALUES_,COUNT(__VA_ARGS__))(__VA_ARGS__)
// chain
#define NAMED_VALUES_1(a) #a,a
#define NAMED_VALUES_2(a,...) #a,a,NAMED_VALUES_1(__VA_ARGS__)
#define NAMED_VALUES_3(a,...) #a,a,NAMED_VALUES_2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define NAMED_VALUES_4(a,...) #a,a,NAMED_VALUES_3(__VA_ARGS__)
#define NAMED_VALUES_5(a,...) #a,a,NAMED_VALUES_4(__VA_ARGS__)
#define NAMED_VALUES_6(a,...) #a,a,NAMED_VALUES_5(__VA_ARGS__)
#define NAMED_VALUES_7(a,...) #a,a,NAMED_VALUES_6(__VA_ARGS__)
#define NAMED_VALUES_8(a,...) #a,a,NAMED_VALUES_7(__VA_ARGS__)
#define NAMED_VALUES_9(a,...) #a,a,NAMED_VALUES_8(__VA_ARGS__)
```

This supports up to 9 arguments, but it should be easy to see how to expand to more.

Comment: Just curious: Does this also work with msvc? Their preprocessor handles variadic macro parameters a bit differently.

Comment: @MikeMB No, it won't.  [Here's an approach that will](https://godbolt.org/g/NB8B8x); unfortunately it can't use the same kind of patterning (to "chain" like this in MSVC requires `CALL` macros to prevent `__VA_ARGS__` from being collapsed into a single arg; but since that runs with `CALL` blue painted it cannot nest).

Answer (score 4):

I think the best you can achieve from inside the language is writing a macro `LOG_API_CALL(foo,bar)` that expands to `log_api_call("foo", foo, "bar", bar)`:

```
#define LOG_API_CALL(P1,P2) log_api_call(#P1,P1,#P2,P1)
```

This gets pretty tricky if you want to support arbitrarily many arguments with a single macro name, but you could also have a separate macro for each number of arguments.

Comment: Nice one, just edited to ask exactly that for not-defined number of parameters

Comment: @DsCpp: I have that code lying around, but it is not pretty and I'm currently on my mobile, so I wouldn't trust myself to replicate it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

> and it would expand to `log_api_call("foo", foo, "bar",bar)` somehow.

This is not possible in Standard C++.